# Question about 'Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Frameworks, Libraries and Other Technologies'

Tags: discussion, survey-2017

I get on the surface that [this insight is about frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-frameworks-libraries-and-other-technologies) that developers are using and want to continue to use, are using and do not want to continue to use, and are not using but want to start to use.

But it seems really odd to me that the 'loved vs dread' are inverses of each other.

```
**Loved**           **Dreaded** **Total** 
React               React       
66.90%              33.10%      100.00%
Node.js             Node.js     
62.10%              37.90%      100.00%
.NET Core           .NET Core       
60.90%              39.10%      100.00%
Spark               Spark       
60.10%              39.90%      100.00%
Firebase            Firebase        
52.90%              47.10%      100.00%
AngularJS           AngularJS       
51.70%              48.30%      100.00%
Hadoop              Hadoop      
48.80%              51.20%      100.00%
Xamarin             Xamarin     
48.70%              51.30%      100.00%
Cordova             Cordova     
38.80%              61.20%      100.00%
```

The description for 'dreaded' was *'% of developers who are developing with the language or technology but have not expressed interest in continuing to do so'*. To me, that is not the same as *'[regarded with great fear or apprehension](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dreaded)'* and/or *'set the machine on fire and walked away'*.

To me, this insight would be more meaningful

1. If the list were longer, like with '[Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-languages)'
2. If there were a documented lukewarm response
3. They put VB at the top of every dreaded list, just to drive home the point.

I would accept any combination of 1, 2, or 3.

More seriously, I would be much more interested to know the breakdown between loved vs meh vs dread/hate. Do 51% of all developers that are using Hadoop really want to shut it down, or is there a large share that are fine with it, but not necessarily going to live or die by it? So it ends up being more like 50% want to keep using Hadoop, 30% are lukewarm, and 20% want to stop it. That tells me more if I am trying to make a decision about my own team's plans. As it stands, it reads a little like introducing Angular could potentially tear my team apart (51 love, 49 dread).

I could see there being some issues in designing a survey around three options vs a binary, but the output, to me, would seem more valuable.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a good source to base your decision on for a framework in the first place.  Honestly, if this is what you're using to base a framework decision on, and not what features it has, how well it matches up to your needs, what the experiences of the specific developers who will be using it feel about it, their experiences, etc. then *that* seems concerning.

Comment: Sure - my thoughts are more in response to the stated purpose of the survey - "we run this survey and share these results to improve developers’ lives: We want to empower developers by providing them with rich information about themselves, their industry, and their peers. And we want to use this information to educate employers about who developers are and what they need."

Comment: Totally agree with @Servy, like everything in software, depends on the situation and their needs.

Comment: Yes, yes, criteria mentioned by @Servy are all good, but guess what: We are all busy people and we simply don't have time to read up on every technology out there. Of course we are talking about beach reading - 'what is used by our fellow programmers out there?', not making important tech stack choices for a next big project. In the latter, making a throughout research is still a must.
I'd also like to see results coming from a multiple choice survey.

Comment: I think problems with such surveys partially arise from the fact, that languages/frameworks/etc. are all being tossed into a single bag with no regard to the fact, that they are all used for completely different tasks/domains. Erlang, JavaScript, C, R - whatever, they're all languages, so let's benchmark them against each other. Take a look at O'Reilly's survey. IMO they did a slightly better job at grouping. For any language/technology they also show what users abandoning it are likely to switch to. e.g. C++→Java, Java→Scala.

Comment: The 2018 results are out and happened the same, the Dreaded/Loved results are just the same list inverted